# How can I show all of objects in NSMutable Array on text field?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I want to show all objects in mutable array on to textfield, label, something else except NSLog

```
   - (IBAction)purchasePressed:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *addItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[addItem addObject:@"Almond"];
[addItem addObject:@"Choc"];
```

"number" is my label (I'm not sure that all of Objects in MutableArray can be showed on textfield or not?)  i can do it only with NSLog.

```
for (i = 0;i < [addItem count] ; i++ )
{
   NSLog(@"%@", addItem);
    NSString *test1=(@"%@", addItem);
    number.text=test1;
}
```

Comment: You might want to use the Objective-C for in loop. for (NSString *string in addItem) {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you set the `text` of a label you replace the previous text.

Try replacing your whole loop with something like:

```
number.text = [addItem componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Which will create a single string from all of the strings in the array and add that to the label. You could do something similar in your loop if you want to.

Comment: Just curiosity, Wain: What if we had a huge collection of NSStrings, is there an equivalent version of enumerate array using block for this?

Comment: @Unheilig, to do what exactly? A custom concatenation of the strings? `NSArray` provides enumeration with a block, what you do with it is your choice...

Comment: @Wain Thank you so much, can I ask you more about how could I count all objects in mutableArray?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string with all the values concatenated:

```
NSString *mainString = [NSString alloc] init]; 

for (NSString *item in addItem) {

    mainString = [mainString stringByAppendingString:item];
}

number.text = mainString;
```

EDIT: Using NSMutableString

```
NSMutableString *mainString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSString *item in addItem) {

    [mainString appendString:item];
}

number.text = mainString;
```

Comment: Would you not use a mutable string?

Comment: I've got error in  [mainString appendingString:item];
with no visible @interface for'NSMutableString' declares the selector'appending string:'

Comment: Sorry I've made ane typing error. Use appendString instead appendingString. I've edit my previous answer.